# Couldn't understand this method summary at Apache commons API documentation

Tags: java

I've found this method summary from Apace Commons APIDOC but I don't understand how to use it.

```
byte[]  decode(String pArray)
          Decodes a String containing containing characters in the Base64 alphabet.
```

Can you give the example of the syntax. I couldn't find the syntax in APIDOCs.

PS : this is from base64 decoding part. I understand the concept but want to use this method. I am looking for example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code example as requested:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

void example() {    
    String srr = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("c:\\test.txt"));
    byte b[]; 
    Base64 base64 = new Base64();
    b=base64.decode(srr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is a scheme for representing bytes as String. If a String is a Base64 string, you pass it as argument to this method, and it returns the original bytes.

[Here is your method](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html)

Comment: you have shown the code. You call the method (staticly) passing a String, and you get a byte array

Comment: where is the method. which class contains the method. which libraries will be required to have that class.

Comment: Gave you a link in my answer.

Comment: String srr = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("c:\\test.txt"));
byte b[] = new byte[16];

how do i decode Contents of encoded string srr into byte b[]